# How to power an outdoor DJ Set?

Tags: audio, field-recording, power

I occasionally see videos of outdoor DJ sets is places that look like they are far from any standard power source. There are many on YouTube but here is an example:

.

How are these normally powered assuming there isn't any place onsite to plug power into? Is it normally just a noisy gas generator that is placed far off camera, a portable battery, or is there a different way to do it? Many of the DJs just have headphones on and there is no audience and so it looks like they wouldn't need a lot of wattage for amplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generators are noisy (audible) and noisy (electrical).

Best bet is some form of battery system that can output a sinusoidal wave (try to avoid square waves!). You could run a solar rig into the battery to keep it topped up.

It depends on the amount of gear you want to run - check the watt usage on each item, convert to kVA and find a suitable battery and convertor (e.g. 12v to 240v) to power it all.

Comment: One of my instruments is an analog synth (Moog Sub 37). Would that work with the type of batter you mentioned?